# Binding service/process to interface in case of exposing it in docker

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, docker-swarm

I would like to understand how exposing port in docker works internally, namely I would like to know which interfaces on host are used. Let's consider three cases:

(1)

```
docker run -p 80:80 nginx
```

(2)
`dokcer-compose:` for *docker swarm*

```
....
services:
    ports:
        published: 80
        target: 80       
....
```

Please not that in this case we use `overlay` network.
(3)
`dokcer-compose:` for *docker swarm*

```
....
services:
    ports:
        published: 80
        target: 80       
        mode: host
....
```

First of all, let's highlight the fact that it depends on process enclosed in container which interface it choose
to bind. However, where it is binded in host? I mean which interface (lo, eth0..) is chosen as interface to bind?

In particluarity, what is difference between (2) and (3) approach?

**Edit**
Let's consider fourth case:
(4)

```
`dokcer-compose:` for *docker swarm*

....
services:
  s1:
    ports:
        published: 1234
        target: 1234       
        mode: host
    networks:
        n1
  s2:
    ports:
        published: 1234
        target: 1234       
        mode: host
    networks:
        n1
networks:
  n1:
    driver: overlay
```

where `s1`, and `s2` are forced to be deployed on different nodes (using constraints).  Now, let's assume that `s1` talk to `s2` and `s2` talk to `s1` using port `1234` and:
(1) IP address of service (or name of service)
(2) IP address of host (physical address).

Tell me please, if in case (1) or (2) overlay network `n1` is used. Please note that both services are connected in this network.

Answer (score 1):

You should get your answers clearly on the documentation

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#publish-a-services-ports-directly-on-the-swarm-node

In your case (2)

```
services:
    ports:
        published: 80
        target: 80
```

If you have 3 nodes `N1,N2,N3`, then hitting `80` on any of the 3 nodes will take you to the application even if it is just deployed on one Node `N3` lets assume.

In `Case (3)`

```
services:
    ports:
        published: 80
        target: 80       
        mode: host
```

Since the service is deployed on `N3` only you get access to 80 on `N3` only, `N1` and `N2` will not respond on the port `80`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of this fact. However, I edited question and added fourth case. Could you answer to my doubts?

Comment: Case 4 is invalid, you can't deploy 2 services with same port on same node if you constraint it, it will fail to load

Comment: Tarun, I meant services with the same port, however on *different* nodes (what can be assured using constraints).